# Python nested json

Tags: python-3.x, django, dictionary, django-rest-framework

Can any one have solution for this, i want there should be api data in this manner ??
I wanted api data in for similar state comes in one hood rather than seprate, different state data can be different obj,

```
    data = [{
        state_name:New_jersi, data:{
            category:Phishing,
            sub_cat_data:[{
                name:SubCat1,
                count:20
            },
            {
                name:SubCat2,
                count:30
            }]
        }
            category: malware,
            sub_cat_data:[{
                name:SubCat1,
                count:20
            },
            {
                name:SubCat2,
                count:30
            }]
    
    },
{
    state_name:Washinton, data:{
        category:Phishing,
        data:[{
            name:SubCat1,
            count:20
        },
        {
            name:SubCat2,
            count:30
        }]
    }
}]

But may api response be:


 {
            "state": "South Carolina",
            "state_count": 2,
            "Website Compromise/Intrusion": {
                "sub_category": {
                    "Insecure Direct Object Reference": 2,
                    "Memory Corruption": 2,
                    "SQLI": 1,
                    "Stack Overflow": 1,
                    "XSRF": 1,
                    "Heap Overflow": 1,
                    "Security Misconfiguration": 1
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "state": "South Carolina",
            "state_count": 1,
            "Phishing": {
                "sub_category": {
                    "Spear Phishing Attacks": 2,
                    "Fast Flux": 2,
                    "Rock fish": 2,
                    "Identify Theft/Social Engineering": 1,
                    "Phishing Redirector": 1,
                    "Pharming": 1,
                    "Exploitation of Hardware Vulnerability": 1
                }
            }
        },
```

i wanted same state data be in same object buut in my case state data comes in seprate object because of data comes through category, rather that seprate.

**My logic are below**

```
            cat_count = incnum.values('incident_category__cat_name','incident_category__cat_id').annotate(count=Count('incident_category__cat_id'))
            subcat_count = incnum.values('incident_sub_category__sub_cat_name','incident_sub_category__cat_id','incident_sub_category__id').annotate(count=Count('incident_sub_category__cat_id'))
            
            reporter_state_count1 = incnum.values('incident_category__cat_id','reporter__comp_individual_state','reporter__comp_individual_state__name').annotate(count=Count('incident_category__cat_id'))



            for x, state_ in enumerate(reporter_state_count1):
                for i, cat_ in enumerate(cat_count):
                    if state_['incident_category__cat_id'] == cat_['incident_category__cat_id']:
                        for i, cat_ in enumerate(cat_count):
                            if state_['incident_category__cat_id'] == cat_['incident_category__cat_id']:
                                arr16.append({'state':state_['reporter__comp_individual_state__name'], 'state_count':state_['count'], cat_['incident_category__cat_name']:{'sub_category':{}}})
                                for sub_ in subcat_count:
                                    if cat_['incident_category__cat_id'] == sub_['incident_sub_category__cat_id']:
                                        arr16[i][cat_['incident_category__cat_name']]['sub_category'].update({sub_['incident_sub_category__sub_cat_name']:sub_['count']})
```

Comment: i dont know the soln but your query has gone to n*4 how will you handle and optimize data records if you have 100k records.

Answer (score 1):

```py
cat_count = incnum.values('incident_category__cat_name', 'incident_category__cat_id').annotate(
    count=Count('incident_category__cat_id'))
subcat_count = incnum.values('incident_sub_category__sub_cat_name', 'incident_sub_category__cat_id',
                             'incident_sub_category__id').annotate(count=Count('incident_sub_category__cat_id'))

reporter_state_count1 = incnum.values('incident_category__cat_id', 'reporter__comp_individual_state',
                                      'reporter__comp_individual_state__name').annotate(
    count=Count('incident_category__cat_id'))

arr16 = []
for state_ in reporter_state_count1:
    state_data = {"state_name" : state_['reporter__comp_individual_state__name'], "data":[]}
    for cat_ in cat_count:
        if state_['incident_category__cat_id'] == cat_['incident_category__cat_id']:
            sub_cat_data = [{sub_['incident_sub_category__sub_cat_name']: sub_['count']} for sub_ in subcat_count if cat_['incident_category__cat_id'] == sub_['incident_sub_category__cat_id']]
            category_data = {"category": cat_['incident_category__cat_name'], "sub_cat_data": sub_cat_data}
            state_data["data"].append(category_data)

    arr16.append(state_data)
```

1 State might have multiple category, the way you are trying to make your api,  it won't be able to show multiple category for a state. This is why i modify a little bit. you will find all the category in state object

**Edit**

Creating a dictionary which will store category_id as key and all the subcategory of that category as value

```py
cat_to_subcat_list = {}
for cat_ in cat_count:
    sub_cat_data = [{"name":sub_['incident_sub_category__sub_cat_name'],"count": sub_['count']} for sub_ in subcat_count if
                    cat_['incident_category__cat_id'] == sub_['incident_sub_category__cat_id']]
    cat_to_subcat_list[cat_['incident_category__cat_id']] = {"category": cat_['incident_category__cat_name'], "sub_cat_data": sub_cat_data}
```

Createing a dictionary which will store state__name as key and a list of category object will save as value

```py
state_data = {}
for state_ in reporter_state_count1:
    if state_['reporter__comp_individual_state__name'] not in state_data:
        '''This if statement is checking whether state_name exit or not.
         if state_name does not exist in dictionary it'll create a empty list  as it's value'''
        state_data[state_['reporter__comp_individual_state__name']] = []
    state_data[state_['reporter__comp_individual_state__name']].append(cat_to_subcat_list[state_['incident_category__cat_id']])
```

Re-formatting json as api needed

```py
arr16 = [
    {
        "state_name": state_name,
        "data": state_data

    }for state_name, state_data in state_data.items()
]
```

Comment: Hey @Aninda still getting after modificaton on code: on seprate - state:

Comment: @deepak can you show me your json object and tell me which  state data is not in that state object ?

Comment: hey @Aninda i'm gettting state data in this way, that why i getting, state repeat data:
{'incident_category__cat_id': 4, 'reporter__comp_individual_state': 3966, 'reporter__comp_individual_state__name': 'South Carolina', 'count': 1}
{'incident_category__cat_id': 1, 'reporter__comp_individual_state': 3966, 'reporter__comp_individual_state__name': 'South Carolina', 'count': 1}
{'incident_category__cat_id': 6, 'reporter__comp_individual_state': 3966, 'reporter__comp_individual_state__name': 'South Carolina', 'count': 2}

Comment: State repeat data meaning, you are getting same state object multiple times?

Comment: yes there are same state but different category, data coming in category wise..

Comment: @deepak i've edited my answer, do check that and let me know

Comment: Hey @Aninda  its work fine, api result as expected, but in sub_category it comes with all pervious other state same category data come,  thanku very much

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you are telling me that you are getting same sub_category in multiple state . if that's the case, i would say it's expected behavior ...... Suppose sub_cat "1" belong to category "2", and category 2 belong both "South Carolina" and "Washinton" .

Comment: but in that case we miss the count for here add by category, 
but expected be from category to state_wise;

suppose in a category we have sub_cat1: count(1) in Washinton
supppose in same category and same sub_catgory: (1) in South Carolina

Api response be for both state: 
   {
                            "Fast Flux": 2
                        },
                        
 but the expected response be:
 
    {
                            "Fast Flux": 1
                        },
 for both states
 I hope you get what i'm telling.

Comment: @deepak add more details in your question. you should mention all this logic in your question. also add some sample data for `cat_count` , `subcat_count`  and `reporter_state_count1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244975/discussion-between-deepak-and-aninda).

Comment: {"state_data":[{"state_name":"South Carolina","data":[{"category":"Phishing","sub_cat_data":[{"Spear Phishing Attacks":2},{"Fast Flux":3},{"Rock fish":2},{"Identify Theft/Social Engineering":2},{"Vishing":1},{"Exploitation of Software Vulnerability":2},{"Exploitation of Hardware Vulnerability":2},{"Pharming":1}]}]},{"state_name":"Louisiana","data":[{"category":"Phishing","sub_cat_data":[{"Spear Phishing Attacks":2},{"Fast Flux":3},{"Rock fish":2},{"Identify Theft/Social Engineering":2},{"Vishing":1},{"Exploitation of Hardware Vulnerability":2},{"Pharming":1}]}]}

Comment: I here post sampe here we getting Phishing Category data for sub_category get same data for both state in this case, we getting adding of Phishing in all states if washington has 1 category for this and if Los Angles has 10 phising category then we get adding of all Phishing categroy in every state not specifc. for every state.